# trouble connecting firebase to angular 15 app

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli

I created a brand new angular application using angular 15, set up a a very brief firestore database with a collection in my firebase project, & ran the following cli commands in my angular app:

- npm install firebase
- npm install -g firebase-tools
- firebase login --reauth
- ng add @angular/fire

which resulted in the following error in the chrome dev tools:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).

any help would be greatly appreciated